How can one display the name of the folder in which a given message is stored Thunderbird for macOS?
How can one display the name of the folder (better: the path) in which a given message is stored Thunderbird for macOS?

Please [edit] your question and add some background information. What do you want to achieve? All message in an IMAP folder are stored in a single binary file. What do you want to do with the information where it is stored? see https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-thunderbird-stores-user-data and https://support.mozilla.org/bm/questions/1369939 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox#Modified_mbox

I am using pop, so my messages are stored locally in folders and I want to locate them.

Please add all information to the question.

Press Select columns to display
Select the Location column to display
The actual foldername will be displayed. If you hover over the location, the path will be displayed.

Thanks a lot. It is too bad that this is only available in the "table view", which is hardly usable for current management.

Is this really the only way? It's very inconvenient...
